# webapp resources into target

Tags: java, maven, maven-war-plugin

web resources are not being copied over to the target/classes folder and hence not in target/${finalName}/WEB-INF/classes folder.

at the moment the output from `mvn clean install`:

`target/classes/(src/main/java)`

however I am also trying to get:

`target/classes/(src/main/webapp)`

pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>StrategicTestArchitecture</groupId>
  <artifactId>STATestAPI</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
  <!--        <configuration>
            <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <webResouces>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                <targetPath>WEB-INF/classes</targetPath>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>${baseDir}/src/main/webapp</directory>
                <targetPath>target/${finalName}/WEB-INF</targetPath>
            </resource>
          </webResouces>
        </configuration> -->
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>Spring.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
    </resources>
  </build>
  <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>staging</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>environment</name>
                    <value>staging</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <hibernate.dialect>org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</hibernate.dialect>
                <hibernate.show_sql>true</hibernate.show_sql>
                <hibernate.url>myoracleurl</hibernate.url>
                <DriverClassName>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</DriverClassName>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>alpha</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <hibernate.dialect>org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</hibernate.dialect>
                <hibernate.show_sql>true</hibernate.show_sql>
                <hibernate.url>myoracleurl</hibernate.url>
                <DriverClassName>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</DriverClassName>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
  <properties>
        <!-- Generic properties -->
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>

        <!-- SPRING & HIBERNATE / JPA -->
        <spring.version>4.3.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.2.5.Final</hibernate.version>

  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>StrategicTestArchitecture</groupId>
        <artifactId>Commons</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Can anyone shed some light as to why these files are not being copied into the output directory?

Comment: You do not need any of that configuration. `mvn clean install` will build a correctly structured WAR file from `src/main/java`, `src/main/resources` and `src/main/webapp` by default.

Comment: removing the configuration made no changes to the output :(
everything under src/main/webapp is in the root of the war and target/$finalName but not in target/classes where we need them to be :/

Comment: Why do you want your webapp resources in `target/classes`?

Comment: When we want users to access our ui we had to add the following: registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:resources/"); in our spring config, is there a better way to expose our html etc? *edit - resources being under src/main/webapp/

Comment: Please show your full pom file...it looks like there something wrong...

Comment: You have copy/pasted `registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLoca‌​tions("classpath:res‌​ources/");` without understanding what it does. Just put your web resources (html, css, images and other assets) in `src/main/webapp/`. They will then be accessible at `http://yourserver:port/appname/`*here*.

Comment: Yup changed it to .addResourceLocations("resources/") that seemed to fix it, before we were putting out content on the classpath as the jetty plugin for eclipse reads from target/classes. so the content as you have mentioned is now at the root of the war and appname/resources/index.html works

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Steve C, the web resources do not need to be on the classpath and therefore the web configuration can be left blank. This will copy everything from the `src/main/webapp` directory into the root of the war file.

In my case we have a folder called resources located at `src/main/webapp/resources` which contains our html/css/js

For reference in the spring config the registryhandler can modified as such:

```
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry){
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("resources/");
}
```